# C++ unexpected identifier

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, identifier

```
#include "cs163hw1.h"

extras::extras(int num_cats){
head = new category_node;
head->next = NULL;
head->category = num_cats;
category_node * temp;
for(int i = 1; i < (num_cats); ++i){
    temp = new category_node;
    temp->next = head;
    head = temp;
    head->category = (num_cats-i);
}
}

extras::~extras(){
category_node * temp;
while(head->next){
    temp = head;
    head = head->next;
    delete temp;
}
delete head;
}

extras::int print_cats(){
category_node * current;
while(current){
    cout << current->category << endl;
    current = current->next;
}
return 1;
}
```

I am getting an unidentified identifier error at the int before print_cats.  It's been a little while since I used c++, but I think I remember that being a lack of ";" error, but for the life of me I haven't found it.

Comment: Did you mean `int extras::print_cats()`? The double colons (scope resolution operator) are used for qualifying, and the `print_cats` is what needs to be qualified, not the `int`.

Comment: That's right, I forgot the order, thank you!

Comment: not sure but looks like category_node is a type, so category_node * current; is declaring a pointer that you don't initialize and you also use on the next line.  while(current)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure, but should it be "`int extras::print_cats()`" instead.

Answer (score 1):

int extras::print_cats() 
If this is a method.

Answer (score 0):

This will work `int extras::print_cats()`. Just a small syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

You likely did not mean `extras::int`, but rather `int`.  The only way that would make sense would be if you had a typedef called int in a namespace or class (and that would be a bad idea).